# NOT ABLE TO CAPTURE no_data_found error in error logs table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have one stored procedure when I am passing one input parameter. With that input parameter, if there is no_data_found then I am raising the exception trying to store no_data_found error in that error logs table but I am not able to do it. Please find my code below,

Stored Procedure:

```
create or replace procedure dumm_proc (p_opportunity_number cct_opportunity.opportunity_number%type)
as

v_oppo_id varchar2(50);
l_message varchar2(50) := sqlerrm;
l_code varchar2(50) := sqlcode;

begin

select opportunity_id into v_oppo_id 
from cct_opportunity
where opportunity_number =  p_opportunity_number;


exception
when no_data_found then
raise;
xxcct_error_logs(cct_error_seq.nextval,null,v_oppo_id,null,null,l_message,l_code,'dumm_proc',null,sysdate,user,sysdate,user);

when others then
xxcct_error_logs(cct_error_seq.nextval,null,v_oppo_id,null,null,l_message,l_code,'dumm_proc',null,sysdate,user,sysdate,user);

end;
```

Storing the values into the table using another error log procedure (xxcct_error_logs) but always it stores with normal, successful completion.

Please suggest how can I store no_data_found error by calling error_logs procedure.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is Since you are assigning the values of l_message,l_code before the exception is raised to by default the executon is always normal. Hope this snippet helps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE dumm_proc(
    p_opportunity_number cct_opportunity.opportunity_number%type)
AS
  v_oppo_id VARCHAR2(50);
  l_message VARCHAR2(50) := sqlerrm;
  l_code    VARCHAR2(50) := SQLCODE;
BEGIN
  SELECT opportunity_id
  INTO v_oppo_id
  FROM cct_opportunity
  WHERE opportunity_number = p_opportunity_number;
EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN
  --  raise;
  l_message:=SQLERRM;
  l_code   :=SQLCODE;
  xxcct_error_logs(cct_error_seq.nextval,NULL,v_oppo_id,NULL,NULL,l_message,l_code,'dumm_proc',NULL,sysdate,USER,sysdate,USER);
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  l_message:=SQLERRM;
  l_code   :=SQLCODE;
  xxcct_error_logs(cct_error_seq.nextval,NULL,v_oppo_id,NULL,NULL,l_message,l_code,'dumm_proc',NULL,sysdate,USER,sysdate,USER);
END;
```

Below snippet for easy understanding

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
  l_message VARCHAR2(100):=SQLERRM;
  l_code    VARCHAR2(100):=SQLCODE;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(l_message||'-->'||l_code);
END;

--Now raising exception forcefully

    SET serveroutput ON;
    DECLARE
      l_message VARCHAR2(100):=SQLERRM;
      l_code    VARCHAR2(100):=SQLCODE;
      l_var PLS_INTEGER;
    BEGIN
      BEGIN
        l_var:='abc';
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
        l_message:=SQLERRM;
        l_code   :=SQLCODE;
      END;
      dbms_output.put_line(l_message||'-->'||l_code);
    END;
```

Comment: above snippets helps but just one doubt, from my code I need to capture select..INTO value also in my error_logs table.... as per my code I need to insert v_oppo_id also should be inserted into error_logs table.

Comment: please ignore my previous question. your snippets are helpful and it got worked.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`raise` ends execution and passes the exception back up to the caller, so the call to the error logger is unreachable:

```
exception
    when no_data_found then
        raise;
        xxcct_error_logs(cct_error_seq.nextval, ... );
```

As a first step, I would change it to:

```
exception
    when no_data_found then
        xxcct_error_logs(cct_error_seq.nextval, ... );
        raise;
```

The error logger seems to have a lot of parameters. Probably it can figure out most of those details itself, and all you need to pass in is a description of what the procedure was trying to do that failed.

Edit:

I missed that you populated variables for the exception details before the error. At that point there was no error. You need to capture the details in the exception handler. You don't even need variables for this. Why not just:

```
xxcct_error_logs
( cct_error_seq.nextval
, null
, v_oppo_id
, null
, null
, sqlerrm    -- Just capture sqlerrm here
, sqlcode
, 'dumm_proc'
, null
, sysdate
, user
, sysdate
, user );
```

Or even simpler, don't pass it at all. Inside the `xxcct_error_logs` procedure it can check whether `sqlcode = 0` and if not it can pick up `sqlerrm`. While you're at it, you could have it take care of `cct_error_seq.nextval` instead of requiring every caller to know what sequence to use; the same goes for the user, timestamp etc etc. My log procedure looks like this:

```
procedure msg
    ( p_message           dsl_log.message%type
    , p_started_timestamp dsl_log.log_timestamp%type default null )
```

Comment: i've changed the exception block as you've suggested but still its storing value as "ORA-0000: normal, successful completion" instead of "ORA-0143: no_data_found".

Comment: Just noticed you capture `sqlerrm` before there is any error. That's why it's reporting success. I'll update my answer with more details when I get a chance.